# Does anyone recognize this titanium frame?

Tags: identify-this-bike, titanium, racing-bikes

I bought this titanium frame some time ago. No markings, only the serial number on the bottom bracket. The 84 probably stands for 1984 as the bike was fitted with Campy's 50th Anniversary gruppo. The BB is Italian threaded. 
Any ideas?

[image: Frame]
[image: Bottom of bottom bracket showing cable guides and serial number]

Comment: I had seen that guides on bottom brackets for derailleur cables on Vitus frames, and the fact that it's built with titanium makes me think this can be a Vitus frame. But it's just an idea...

Comment: I would ask in the C&V subforum over at Bikeforums. I'd be surprised if someone doesn't know. http://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/

Comment: I'm tempted to say it's mine.

Comment: Ship it to me for further inspection ^^

Comment: Did you find out what the bike is? I have one of these bikes as well and have serial number 47, see below...

Comment: Bog-standard in terms of design.  No real distinguishing characteristics, other than the serial number.  The downtube shifter bosses suggest it's fairly old (practically an antique for titanium).

Comment: Italian BB makes me think possibly passoni or chesini, but I haven’t seen that serial number plate and format before.

Comment: @AndrewWatson They do look like plates of the same style.  Could you please add another answer that shows what you know about yours.   When you got it, any info of relevance at all.  Even what country you got it in could be useful.  Can you get hold of the previous owner at all?  Or post a couple of full photos so OP can compare the two frames.

Answer (score 1):

This frame has some features in common with [this Fracesco Moser frame I saw](https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.182701288550064.1073741855.172457916241068&type=1). But there are differences, as well: the chainstays, and the fork.

Comment: The above picture is a near-identical match to a 1984 Moser, if this Pinterest post is to be trusted:  https://www.pinterest.com/pin/211950726189306619/?lp=true

Comment: Image link requires a Facebook account, so this answer is pretty much useless.

Answer (score 1):

It was designed by Coassin, welded Manfredi (Comepre), might have been built for Tigra's racing team (see https://www.speedbicycles.ch/velo/517/tigra_242_titan_1976.html)

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  You should include some details from your link so this answer is still useful if it goes away.

Answer (score -2):

This purports to be a 1984 Moser:

[image: https://www.pinterest.com/pin/211950726189306619/?lp=true]

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/211950726189306619/?lp=true

Looks pretty much identical to the OP's frame.

Comment: This one has lugs, the OP's frame has smooth welds.

Comment: Other obvious differences include seatstay joint, fork crown and front derailleur mount. All together, they are about as different as two 80s road bikes can be.

Comment: @ojs - Yeah, I missed that detail.

Comment: @ojs - I don't see a difference in FD mount.  The OP's frame has a dent/abrasion there, and the FD in my link appears to be clamp-on.  But it may well be that the frame in my link is steel (Google/Pinterest was not helpful in confirming material), and hence the difference in joints.

Comment: Aside from the differences in joints then, what aspects of that photo prove it is a moser? I don't know enough to rule it in, or rule it out, it needs a bit more explanation

Comment: @daniel r Hicks The dent you’re referring to on the seat tube is clearly the remnants of a welded FD mount, so it was originally distinct from the clamp-on seen on the other bike.

Comment: If you look at the OP's bike, there is a FD braze on, not a dent.

Comment: All road bikes from late 70s to early 90s have similar thin tubes, almost exact same geometry and one of about two dropout styles. The only way to tell them apart is lugs, braze ons and possible engravings.